# Editing the contents of an Array of Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have some doubts regarding how to change the contents of an array (of strings) in JavaScript. If  I have an Array like this:

`var name = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"];`

and I want to convert it into an array like this:

```
var name = ["A","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"];
```

That is, I have to remove some of its elements. I know the starting and ending indices of the elements to be removed, like in the above example I removed all strings between "A" and "D"(I am given the indices of "A" and "D").
How can I do so?

Note:Here is the function in which i modified the array. Here, when I pass the function, s=1, e=3.

```
function replace(s,e)
{ var k= new Array();
k=name.splice(s,e-s);
cpyarr(k,name,k.length); }
```

cpyarr(arr1,arr2,n) is a function created to copy from arr1 to arr2 (n elements)

I am getting error in `k=name.splice(s,s-e)` line

Comment: [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Why was this upvoted?

Comment: I used name.splice(1,2), but there is an error:Uncaught TypeError: name.splice is not a function.

Comment: `name.splice(1,2)` works fine for me, perhaps you can show us all of the code that you used when you get `Uncaught TypeError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var name = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"];
function removeSomeElems(arr,indices){
    return arr.filter(function(char,index) { return indices.indexOf(index) == -1 });
}

console.log(removeSomeElems(name,[1,2,4]));
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error 'Uncaught TypeError: arr.filter is not a function'

Comment: because you are not passing an array as first argument in the function invocation.

Comment: Agreed that 'name' is not an array here; then how am i suppose to tackle this problem? Do I need to make an array of arrays??

Comment: in your example name is array! in what type you expect to be variable `'name'`? You don't need to make array of arrays!

Comment: name should be array. call it this way:
`console.log(removeSomeElems(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"],[1,2,4]));`

Comment: okay this works. But what if I want to change the contents again, like after removing "B", "C" I again need to invoke the function to delete some other elements. Also could you please explain why indices=[1,2,4]??